# action: publish:gitlab is failing because of "No matching integration configuration for host https, please check your integrations config"

Tags: backstage

I am creating the following template to enable my team starting project from a custom SpringBoot starter project that I store in `https://gitlab.com/handson-backstage/sf-rest-template` and then push a freshly new project to `https://gitlab.com/handson-backstage/${{parameters.component_id}}`

```
apiVersion: scaffolder.backstage.io/v1beta3
kind: Template
metadata:
  name:  spring-boot-service
  title: Spring Boot Service
  description: Create a new Spring Boot service
  tags:
    - spring-boot
spec:
  owner: guest
  type: service

  parameters:
    - title: Fill in the following parameters for your new service
      required:
        - component_id
        - description
      properties:
        component_id:
          title: Name of the service
          type: string
          description: Unique name of the new service.
        description:
          title: Description of the service
          type: string
          description: Description of the new service.

  steps:
    - id: fetch-base
      name: Fetch Base
      action: fetch:plain
      input:
        url: https://gitlab.com/handson-backstage/sf-rest-template

    - id: publish
      name: Publish
      action: publish:gitlab
      input:
        repoUrl: 'https://gitlab.com/handson-backstage/${{parameters.component_id}}'
        token: some_token
```

But when I want to create a service using this template I get the following error the 2nd step :

```
2023-06-15T08:53:48.000Z Beginning step Publish2023-06-15T08:53:48.000Z InputError: No matching integration configuration for host https, please check your integrations config    
at parseRepoUrl (webpack-internal:///../../plugins/scaffolder-backend/src/scaffolder/actions/builtin/publish/util.ts:58:15)    
at Object.handler (webpack-internal:///../../plugins/scaffolder-backend/src/scaffolder/actions/builtin/publish/gitlab.ts:130:97)    
at NunjucksWorkflowRunner.executeStep (webpack-internal:///../../plugins/scaffolder-backend/src/scaffolder/tasks/NunjucksWorkflowRunner.ts:211:26)    
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)    
at async NunjucksWorkflowRunner.execute (webpack-internal:///../../plugins/scaffolder-backend/src/scaffolder/tasks/NunjucksWorkflowRunner.ts:281:17)    
at async TaskWorker.runOneTask (webpack-internal:///../../plugins/scaffolder-backend/src/scaffolder/tasks/TaskWorker.ts:90:33)    at async run (/Users/ghassentdf/Desktop/Workspace/Projects/backstage/node_modules/p-queue/dist/index.js:163:29)
```

Comment: There is an issue with the integration as per the error message: `No matching integration configuration for host https, please check your integrations config` this is usually located in `app-config.yml`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually the error is coming from the repoUrl: `https://gitlab.com/handson-backstage/${{parameters.component_id}}` line which should be without `https` :

```
repoUrl: 'gitlab.com/handson-backstage/${{parameters.component_id}}'
```